# Is it "a player who always do" or "who always does"?

Tags: grammaticality, grammatical-number, verb-agreement, subordinate-clauses

I have a <s>doubt</s> question or confusion about the following structure:

1. I am a player who always **do** the best.

or

2. I am a player who always **does** the best"

Which is the correct version?

I think the "do" version is the correct one but I am not sure.

Comment: It needs to agree with “a player”, so it is “does”.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: The relative clause agrees with it's antecedent:  _I am a **player** who always **does** the best_ but _**I**, who **do** the best, am a player._ <-- Don't ever do that though.

Comment: Note that your sentences claim you will always be the best player, in any match/game, on any day, in any circumstance, which is a very bold claim.  I suspect you may be looking for _"I am a player who always does **their** best"_, meaning you always give the best of your personal abilities.

Comment: Why it is not "I am a player who always does **his** best"?